# Random sample of size $n = 2k$, calculate $p(X_1 < 1/2, X_2 > 1/2, X_3 < 1/2, X_4 > 1/2, \dots, X_{2k} > 1/2)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

A random sample of size n = 2k is taken from a uniform pdf defined over the unit interval. Calculate $p(X_1 < 1/2, X_2  > 1/2, X_3 < 1/2, X_4 > 1/2,...., X_{2k} > 1/2)$.

Solution: Then the random sample is independent thus,

\begin{align*}
p(X_1& < 1/2, X_2  > 1/2, X_3 < 1/2, X_4 > 1/2,...., X_{2k} > 1/2)\\
&= P(X_1 < 1/2) P(X_2 > 1/2) \cdots (X_{2k} > 1/2).
\end{align*}

Then $P(X_1 < 1/2) = P(X_2 > 1/2) = 1/2$. Thus $p(X_1 > 1/2, X_2  > 1/2, X_3 < 1/2, X_4 > 1/2,\dots, X_{2k} > 1/2) = (1/2)^{2k}.$

Is this correct? Please any feedback is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If commas in $P(\dots,\dots,\dots)$ mean conjunction ("AND"), then your reasoning and answer are true. I may propose anothe solution, perhaps it's a bit simpler.
You may represent the problem as binary number of length $2k$.
If $X_i < 1/2$, then $i^{th}$ digit of the number is $0$, otherwise it's $1$.
Then an outcome described in the problem may be represented as $X^* = 010101\dots01$.
As $P(i^{th}$ digit $ = 0)=P(i^{th}$ digit $ = 1) = 1/2$ and digits are generated independently, we have randomly generated binary number $X$ from $0$ to $2^{2k}$ distributed uniformly and need to find $P(X = X^*)$. It is obviously equal to $1/2^{2k}$, as it's one appropriate outcome out of $2^{2k}$.